# problem in software updater

Tags: apt, update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

I got error in update-manager

> W:Failed to fetch
>   http://archive.canonical.com/commercial-ppa-uploaders/skype/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages
>   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80] , E:Some index files failed to
>   download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

How do I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the ppa you added that is available longer or added outdated PPA.
you have to type following command in terminal to install skype.

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ quantal partner' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list"
```